# Does Latin have a mechanism to disambiguate possessive pronouns of the same gender referring to distinct persons?

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, language-evolution, pronouns, ambiguity

**Question:** does Latin have a grammatical mechanism to disambiguate the ambiguous use of `his' in the third of the three following English sentences?

> Person A wrote a book.
>   Then person B wrote a book.
>   Then person A wrote a book review of B's book,
>   wherein he compared his book with his.

**Remarks**

- In English, a solution is of course to replace the latter "his" with the two words "his own". 
  The question is whether Latin has a mechanism which somehow uses the same possessive pronoun, but "inflected" in different ways.
- More generally, even though this is a Latin-language-forum: what other languages do you know which have a mechanism for this particular disambiguation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two key mechanisms of disambiguation come to mind:

- Using *hic* (latter) and *ille* (former) is one way. Simple example: "A and B meet. The former eats, the latter drinks." — *A et B conveniunt. Ille est, hic bibit.*
- The pronoun *se/suus* usually refers to the subject of the sentence. Simple example: "B wrote a book. A compares his own book with B's." — *B librum scripsit. A librum suum cum libro eius comparat.*

Unfortunately there are cases where *se/suus* refers to something other than a subject.
The risk of misinterpretation is larger than usual in your story, but I guess that is inevitable if you want to use pronouns only.
On the other hand, "comparing X with Y" does not change much if X and Y are interchanged.

Despite the caveat, I think the distinction is best made with the pair *suus/eius*.
Here's how I'd translate your story:

> Aeneas librum scripsit.
>   Deinde Brutus librum scripsit.
>   Deinde Aeneas contemplationem libri Bruti scripsit,
>   in qua librum suum cum libro eius comparavit.

There are better translations for "review" than *contemplatio*, but I decided to let the original translation stay here as its beside the point.
For a more on book reviews, see [this follow-up question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4735/79).

Incidentally, the specification "same gender" in the question is irrelevant for Latin here.
The the form of the pronoun *suus* depends on the thing possessed, not the possessor, and the genitive *eius* is the same for all three genders.
English makes a distinction between "his" and "her(s)", but Latin doesn't.

Regarding other languages:
Many languages have something similar to the Latin *suus*.
Italian has "suo", Swedish has "sin", Finnish has "-nsA", but there are syntactical differences between the languages.
However, to make the distinction clear in any language, I would simply repeat B's name on the last line.

Answer (score 9):

Yep, it's called the *reflexive adjective*, *suus*, -*a*, -*um*. It declines like an adjective and goes with the noun it's modifying.

Examples:

- Marcus reads a book. *Marcus librum legit.*
- Marcus reads his [i.e. someone else's] book. *Marcus **eius** librum legit.*
- Marcus reads his own book. *Marcus **suum** librum legit.*

For the full set of rules on reflexives, see [Allen & Greenough](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/reflexive-pronouns) on the topic.

Comment: I agree that *suus/eius* is the best way to go here. (I had the feeling someone else might be typing up an answer, too. A whopping difference of 19 seconds...)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta 19 seconds is too funny! How odd that we both must have seen it at the same time, yet it had already been on the site for 30 minutes.